# Postgresql Upsert - syntax error on DO UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to perform an Upsert but can't figure out what the correct syntax is. Could someone please help me identify the issue?

```
INSERT INTO owners (contract_address, owner_address, owns_sticker, owns_balloon)
VALUES(
    'cxd70e445647f50560d495d695b7becd3e88083222', 
    'hxfcba5ec13ba9791dcb52de1f8e25ae7625762222',
    1,
    1
) ON CONFLICT (contract_address)
DO UPDATE owners SET owns_sticker = 0, owns_balloon = 0 WHERE contract_address = 
    'cxd70e445647f50560d495d695b7becd3e88083222'
```

Syntax Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "owners"
LINE 8: DO UPDATE owners SET owns_sticker = 0, owns_balloon = 0 WHERE ...
```

I'm following the postgresql tutorial from:

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/

I'm not quite sure how to translate their example to a working one for my situation:

[image]

Comment: You don't need to repeat the table name in the `do update` part. It should be `DO UPDATE SET owns_sticker = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the error reproduced:

```
postgres=# create table owners( contract_address varchar(100) primary key ,owner_address varchar(100),owns_sticker int, owns_balloon int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# INSERT INTO owners (contract_address, owner_address, owns_sticker, owns_balloon)
postgres-# VALUES(
postgres(#     'cxd70e445647f50560d495d695b7becd3e88083222',
postgres(#     'hxfcba5ec13ba9791dcb52de1f8e25ae7625762222',
postgres(#     1,
postgres(#     1
postgres(# );
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from owners;
              contract_address              |               owner_address                | owns_sticker | owns_balloon
--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------
 cxd70e445647f50560d495d695b7becd3e88083222 | hxfcba5ec13ba9791dcb52de1f8e25ae7625762222 |            1 |            1
(1 row)

postgres=# INSERT INTO owners (contract_address, owner_address, owns_sticker, owns_balloon)
postgres-# VALUES(
postgres(#     'cxd70e445647f50560d495d695b7becd3e88083222',
postgres(#     'hxfcba5ec13ba9791dcb52de1f8e25ae7625762222',
postgres(#     1,
postgres(#     1
postgres(# ) ON CONFLICT (contract_address)
postgres-# DO UPDATE owners SET owns_sticker = 0, owns_balloon = 0 WHERE contract_address =
postgres-#     'cxd70e445647f50560d495d695b7becd3e88083222';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "owners"
LINE 8: DO UPDATE owners SET owns_sticker = 0, owns_balloon = 0 WHER...
                  ^
postgres=# INSERT INTO owners (contract_address, owner_address, owns_sticker, owns_balloon)
VALUES(
    'cxd70e445647f50560d495d695b7becd3e88083222',
    'hxfcba5ec13ba9791dcb52de1f8e25ae7625762222',
    1,
    1
) ON CONFLICT (contract_address)
DO UPDATE owners SET owns_sticker = 0, owns_balloon = 0;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "owners"
LINE 8: DO UPDATE owners SET owns_sticker = 0, owns_balloon = 0;
```

And here is the fix:

```
postgres=# INSERT INTO owners (contract_address, owner_address, owns_sticker, owns_balloon)
VALUES(
    'cxd70e445647f50560d495d695b7becd3e88083222',
    'hxfcba5ec13ba9791dcb52de1f8e25ae7625762222',
    1,
    1
) ON CONFLICT (contract_address)
DO UPDATE SET owns_sticker = 0, owns_balloon = 0;
INSERT 0 1
postgres=#
```